# How to connect one model to another more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

*I have quite a specific problem so I'll translate it into more understandable and clear example.*

So we have 'Country' and 'Image' models. A Country has its flag and its arm.

This means we have to connect Country to Image 2 times. I tried transforming Rails guide's recipe 'Connecting to itself', however, I always get an exception: "Image expected, got String".

```
*Country model
   class Country < ApplicationRecord
     has_one :flag, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: 'id'
     has_one :arm,  class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: 'id'
   end

*Image model
   class Image < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :flag, class_name: 'Country'
     belongs_to :arm, class_name: 'Country'
   end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have nothing in the `Image` model to specify if the image is a flag or an arm.

So, add a column `represents` which can be "flag" or "arms" and also ensure that image has a `country_id` integer field, and then set the relationships as...

```
 class Image < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :country
 end

 class Country < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :flag, -> {where represents: 'flag'}, class_name: 'Image'
   has_one :arms, -> {where represents: 'arms'}, class_name: 'Image'
end
```